# How large can a message property be in HornetQ?

Tags: performance, hornetq

I am using HornetQ for email sending.

File attachments are transmitted out-of-band (not as part of the message) using an object storage system. This adds some overhead that I want to avoid for small files by putting them into message properties directly.

I know that I can send huge message bodies, but for large files, object storage works well, this is about small files, and delivery by property value would be very convenient if it works.

What are the considerations for message property values? Can I make them a 100K byte array? Will this slow things down (or even break)?

Comment: FWIW, for really large message headers you need to at least change some configuration. I tried a 22MB message property, and it resulted in  HornetQInternalErrorException "Record is too large to store".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers, Properties and the Body buffer themselves are all combined in relatively straightforward process into the overall buffer for the message, so there should not be significant performance issues from that perspective. You can see the core implementation here:
https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/hornetq-core-client/src/main/java/org/hornetq/core/message/impl/MessageImpl.java

One consideration would be the size of your consumer window size, which by default would only be 1MB. This is the size that will be buffered on the consumer, so if you are sending messages near this size your performance in reading may be much slower as you wait for data at the consumer. This can be changed with the `consumer-window-size` parameter. See http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/flow-control.html#d0e4023 for more information.

Pulling from comments, you'll probably also want to increase your journal size and buffer size. See You'd probably be close to the limits. You would want to site the journal buffer size larger for sure to get some headroom, and probably size up the journal itself as well.  http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.1.1.Final/user-manual/en/html/persistence.html#configuring.message.journal.journal-buffer-size and https://developer.jboss.org/thread/154423

Comment: Hmm. So as long as the message can still fit into the memory of every node involved, it should work okay (just that network throughput may become a contributing factor and that consumer-window buffering might not work -- but that is an option you could in theory turn off anyway to "give deterministic distribution between multiple consumers")?

Comment: Is there a maximum message size I might need to configure (for queue, for consumer or for producer)?

Comment: You were wondering about ~100K messages in your question. If you're considering messages closer to the size of your memory, you'll also need to consider the journal size (default 10M) and a few other buffers. See this discussion with a core JBoss developer: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/154423

Comment: Fair enough. So three properties of 100K each should (with default configuration) not be a problem, right?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would guess the large-message support might not work quite right for properties (or at least, not intuitively).

Comment: You'd probably be close to the limits. You would want to size the journal buffer size larger for sure to get some headroom, and probably size up the journal itself as well.  http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.1.1.Final/user-manual/en/html/persistence.html#configuring.message.journal.journal-buffer-size

Comment: Hmm. It does look a bit scary. Seems safer to keep the whole message below 100K and externalize my email attachments.

Comment: I'd at least move them to the body somehow and then use the large-message support features.